# How can i hide a program from the tray?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I dont't want to tray a program, i want to hide a program FROM the tray.
 I have a program running in the tray, and i want to hide that, also i have screenshot.

[photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S00af.png)

[this answer doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3k1h.png)

Comment: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/stealth-or-hide-running-program-from-appearing-in-taskbar-or-traybar/

Comment: @harrymc these tools don`t work how i asked

Comment: Do you know if the process that provides the tray icon needs to run?  What functionality does it provide for the applicartion?  Some tray icons just provide notifications and give you a way to launch the application for example.  If this is the case, maybe you can just disable the startup entry for the process.  Typically these are a "Run" key in the registry, but as I don't know, I would suggest run Autoruns to find it. https://live.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe.  With this software you can toggle the enable/disable so you can re-instate it easily if needed.

Comment: In regedit... under the RUN subkey under HKLM or HKCU, append /HIDE if it's autorun. Otherwise just call the executable with /HIDE.

Comment: @Nick could you give some screenshots how can i do this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on taskbar (in an "empty" space), select "Properties..." ->
under "Notification area" section, click the "Customize..." button ->
There you can select how the tray icons behave.
That's the standard way.

Comment: it does not work

Comment: What happened, can you describe? By the way, your screenshot looks like Win 8, but you tagged this as windows-7...

Comment: i made all that you says but it isn`t working, i can post some new photos